# Name change as a Permanent Resident of the USA

Tags: us-citizens

I am a permanent resident of the USA. I don't have a First Name, I have only a Last Name. On my Green Card, my first name section says "FNU" which means "First Name Unknown". I wanted to change my name and ordered my name change [here](https://www.legallynamechange.com). They said that I would have an option to change my name at the time of citizenship - the Naturalization Oath Ceremony. Therefore I should not waste my money. So my question is: will I have the option to change my name at the time of citizenship?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, will I have the option to change my name at the time of citizenship?

Yes. You can indicate the name change request in the citizenship application (Form N-400) as well as during the naturalization interview with the USCIS officer. It [may](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/24010/164) however delay the naturalization process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to change your name when you do the naturalization ceremony and officially become a US citizen. They'll want your name to match all your documents at that point. I wouldn't spend money on changing it now if you're going to get citizenship soon anyway. As long as the "FNU" doesn't cause any issues for you in the meantime, I'd just wait till citizenship.